# Placement of code in HTML document affecting SEO

Tags: seo, html, search-engines, website-design, layout

I have a **navigation bar** div with all my navigation code, a **sidebar** div with all my code and content that goes in my static sidebar, a **footer** div with all my footer code that goes in my static footer, and a **content** div with all my content for each page (changes on each page).

Should I list my content div first in my HTML to optimize my SEO since my content is what changes on each page of my website and houses the "meat of my webpage" (although my sidebar does have good content but it is static on all pages), or is it OK to list my navigation code before my content code?

As an extension, if the order I list these div's makes no difference to the appearance of my site, would it make a difference either way how I list the code, or should I play it safe and list my content code first?

**Note:** As far as how this differentiates from other similar questions, I am not inquiring so much about duplicate content as I am about the weight given to code based on its placement within HTML. I know a lot of websites list their navigation code first, so I'm wondering if that would be a bad tactic considering the content is thus listed lower in the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a rule, what makes sense for semantic markup and accessibility usually also makes sense for SEO, and you should certainly not damage usability or code quality for the sake of any SEO that Google have not recommended to webmasters.

On-site SEO should be about helping Google index your site thoroughly and accurately, and not trying to find loopholes in their algorithm.

1. Even if your css works to display the content correctly on a monitor, it will still appear in the wrong order to someone using a screen reader - people expect the main navigation to appear before the content.
2. The HTML5 tags `aside`, `header`, `article`, `nav` and `footer` let html renderers know what part of your page is content and what is template.  I'd be surprised if the search engines do not use this information when it comes to prioritising the content section.

Comment: You make some good points! The only thing I quibble with is ordering HTML with CSS is not a loop hole in the algorithm. Google has even recommended this CSS option as a way of helping to understand the content. I personally prefer just to order the HTML the traditional way but being careful not to over optimize the code. I like your point about screen readers especially! This is often an important consideration that we forget. As well, I am not sure how HTML5 ready Google is- that is, I have not seen much on this. I know that they state that HTML 4 or greater is preferred.

Comment: By a loop hole in the algorithm, I mean more trying to fiddle with your content purely as an attempt to improve rankings rather than to improve the code.  More than anything, such tweaks are usually a lot of effort for very little benefit.  I've never actually seen them recommend putting the navigation after the content.  Do you have a link?

Comment: Also: If they are not using html5 tags, it would still be easy for them to work out what is template and what is content by what code changes on each page.  Simply assuming every site has the content is at the top of the page would not make for a very accurate search engine.

Comment: No link. I just remember this as part of my research. However, pushing content to the top of the HTML is commonly recommended even by Google. The CSS/HTML reordering is often not a big effort. Again, the only real advantage is not confusing content keywords with navigation and sidebar elements which can skew the results. Again, I often state that HTML in traditional order is fine and there is not much difference in performance. I don't reorder my content. I just don't care that much!

Comment: I was saying that I (as in me, myself, and I) was not sure how ready HTML5 Google was- not that I doubt they are HTML5 ready. I know that they have not updated their code to drop fully understanding HTML 4+ Some of what I know is from internal documents that are sometimes shared in research circles. So I am not always sure of what they say publicly. I keep my HTML simple- stupid simple in fact so I do not have to worry about the semantics too much.

Comment: Genuinely can't find a single reference to it from Google on the web.  Their webmaster guidelines don't say a thing.  Ultimately, most ranking is from off-site stuff, so I can't see it making much difference either way if you prefer to code like that.

Comment: The guidelines wouldn't. I would not expect Google to say to order content, navigation, and sidebar using CSS specifically. Google often avoids these types of topics. They do not recommend against it either. I am sure it would not take too long to find Google recommending placing the content as high in the code as possible. Again, I am only talking about effect and that effect is well known and documented- again the difference is only *not to dilute content* keywords. Navigation keywords are important too! I am a traditional sort of guy. But I know that ordering elements via CSS does help.

Comment: because my sidebar and navigation are positioned absolute (I have it this way regardless of SEO because that goes with my design - www.ninjawarrior.info/new/index.html), it is just a question of which component I list first, so that is my primary question here. Also, do you have a good resource on those HTML5 tags?

Comment: It isn't a great resource, but w3schools does the job - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_new_elements.asp - I wouldn't bother re-coding a site in html5 for the sake of SEO, though - search engines are always going to care more about content than code.  Its main benefit is more about code readablility (for people as well as robots).

Comment: Just checked it out. It would seem that those tags would have a huge influence on weighting different pieces of content, am I wrong? Would you say to list my navigation and or sidebar before my content?

Comment: I doubt it would make a big difference.  HTML5 is still quite new and Google seem perfectly able to identify what-is-what on the sites which are not html5.  It may help them avoid getting false-positives, but they most likely will have enough means of working out what is content and what is template without it.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you do not order anything and the `navigation` and `sidebar` `div(s)` appear in the HTML code before the content, Google and Bing can sort this out without too much trouble, however, there is a performance boost, albeit not a huge one, when you can push these elements below the content. The primary reason is because the HTML is read in byte order from left to right top to bottom, and the less you confuse the keyword weight of the content the better. That being said, search engines had to learn how to read HTML well early on so natively, they can figure things out rather well.

I always recommend pushing the various repetitive portions of your HTML down below the content. If you cannot at this point, do not sweat it. But when you can, make the effort. As well, because navigation is an important element and important to search engines, that HTML code should follow your content first. Sidebars carry less weight than navigation so the sidebar should follow navigation. If you have more than one sidebar of repetitive(ish) HTML, then you decide which one is more important and make sure they appear in that order. Remember that navigation is an important SEO element. Also remember that sidebar navigation is a less important SEO element compared to navigation. So it is important to follow tradition and make sure not to confuse this order otherwise your SEO performance may be confused.

Comment: I can push repetitive portions below the content. That is the essense of my qustion. Should I push the navigation below my content (as it is repetitive) or keep that above the content, as you said it carries weight?

Comment: Good question. If your navigation keywords will dilute your content, then I would consider placing it just below the content. If your navigation compliments your content keywords, then I might not bother. @Richard B mentioned nav which helps search engines to know what code is navigation. I have used this tag, but I cannot tell you that it does anything- my fault I am sure. But then again, I have not used this CSS ordering for myself yet mostly because I will be working on a new responsive design template and do not want to work on code that I will be throwing away.

Comment: Just to be clear, I have used the CSS reordering on other sites and I know that search results can be cleaner/tighter/more relevant if done well.

Answer (score 1):

*Google knows what is what before your visitors do*

Google's crawlers have really advanced since there first launch, their crawlers has the ability to detect actual content area, the width of that content as well as the height of the actual content region.

*Repeated Content*

Elements such as headers, footers and sidebars that get repeated on several or all pages are noted by Google and often do not count to the actual page ranks but rather confirm what you have on that page.

*HTML5 is great but it's not required*

With [HTML5 we have many elements](http://html5doctor.com/element-index/) like article, header, footer, section, aside, figure and so on that it's believed that this massively helps Google when in fact there's little to none to suggest that a HTML5 site will rank better than a HTML4 site. This is because Google doesn't just code their bots for webmaster that know what there doing. Different content managements and themes work in different ways and Google attempts to cater for all.

*Page Layout*

Google also knows the importance of being flexible in detecting sidebars on the left, the right navs at the top right, middle and even on the bottom. Google will also be able to adapt to pretty much any design on the menu system after-all the internet would suck if every site was the same.

*Using `Position:Absolute`*

Some websites use [position absolute](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Absolute_positioning) in there CSS code meaning that even NAV menus that are not above the fold appear in order for search engines but again Google knows what is what regardless where it may be found on the page.

*Tug of war Pushing and Pulling*

Many [frameworks](http://responsive.vermilion.com/compare.php) are now starting to use push and pull methods that will change the layout depending what device is being used, but this is generally used for the user not the Search Engines. This is because on mobiles the menu may take up a lot of room while you may want them to dive straight into the content , while on a desktop machine because the resolution is bigger the user will see both the menu and the content.

1. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) for example uses `.col-X-pull-X` and `.col-X-push-X`
2. [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html#source-ordering) uses `X-pull-X` and `X-push-X`

*Experience, Experience, Experience and then Experience*

You should always code for your audience and only ensure that you are doing the essentials to improve SEO like ALT tags, Headers and so on. In the rare event that Google dislikes something it may reduce your SEO value slightly but user experience trumps SEO all day long! and the value of visitors that create natural SEO will counteract any minor a hundreds time over. Off Page SEO remains the best way to remain and increase in rankings.